# Vue Leaflet map not rendering properly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet

I am trying to render an OpenStreet map by vue-leaflet. But I facing an incomplete rendering problem. The map not showing with full view, rather it's loading partially and not sequentially.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3vA1.png)

Here is my code

```
<template>
  <l-map
      v-show="loadingMap"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      :options="{ zoomControl: false }"
    >
      <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
    </l-map>
</template>
```

I found in some StackOverflow answers, it's suggested to import leaflet.css and I added leaflet.css in the main.js file. (for the sandbox example it's in index.html), but still, it's not working

How can I see the map fully & with an actual map view (not partially loaded like now)?

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-glade-1yqe8?file=/src/App.vue:31-212

Answer (score 5):

You missing Leaflet css style. Put it in your `main.js` or Vue component.

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

Then add some style for `#app`

```css
#app {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for vue.js and nuxt.js developers, probably it's because of using **v-show** or **v-if**
but dont worry the only thing u have to do is using clien-only tag like this:

```
<client-only>
<div v-show="someVariable" id="vShowOrVIfExample">
<div id="map-wrap" style="height: 100vh">
   <l-map :zoom=13 :center="[55.9464418,8.1277591]">
     <l-tile-layer url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"></l-tile-layer>
     <l-marker :lat-lng="[55.9464418,8.1277591]"></l-marker>
   </l-map>
 </div>
</div>
</client-only>
```